# Open a text file,sort the text file and then save it using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have found the following Python code from `Stackoverflow` which opens a file called `sort.txt`, and then sorts the the numbers contained in the file.

The code works perfect. I was wondering how I could then save the sorted data to another text file. Every time I try, the saved file is shown empty.
Any help would be appreciated.
I would like the saved file to be called `sorted.txt`

```
with open('sort.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
numbers = [int(e.strip()) for e in lines]
numbers.sort()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this with `f.write()` :

```
with open('sort.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

numbers = [int(e.strip()) for e in lines]
numbers.sort()

with open('sorted.txt', 'w') as f: # open sorted.txt for writing 'w'
    # join numbers with newline '\n' then write them on 'sorted.txt'
    f.write('\n'.join(str(n) for n in numbers))
```

Input (`sort.txt`):

```
1
-5
46
11
133
-54
8
0
13
10
```

Output (`sorted.txt`):

```
-54
-5
0
1
8
10
11
13
46
133
```

Answer (score 1):

With `<file object>.writelines()` method:

```
with open('sort.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    lines = f.readlines()
    numbers = sorted(int(n) for n in lines)
    out.writelines(map(lambda n: str(n)+'\n', numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Get sorted data from the current file and save to a variable.
Open the new file in write mode ('w')and write the data from saved variable to the file.