# Prints to console. Now I want to print to CSV file

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I can read a text file with names and print in ascending order to console. I simply want to write the sorted names to a column in a CSV file. Can't I take the printed(file) and send to CSV?
Thanks!

```
import csv
with open('/users/h/documents/pyprojects/boy-names.txt','r') as file:
    for file in sorted(file):
        print(file, end='')

#the following isn't working. 
with open('/users/h/documents/pyprojects/boy-names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile:
    names = ['Column1']
    writer = csv.writer(names)
    print(file)
```

Comment: Check the docs again for csv.writer: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer. You pass it the file object, then use `writerow` to write each row.

Comment: Related: [Open a text file,sort the text file and then save it using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46057732/2745495)

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the documentation.

The only tricky part is converting the lines from the file to a list of 1-element lists.

```
import csv
with open('/users/h/documents/pyprojects/boy-names.txt','r') as file:
    names = [[k.strip()] for k in sorted(file.readlines())]

with open('/users/h/documents/pyprojects/boy-names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(['Column1'])
    writer.writerows(names)
```

So, `names` will contain (for example):

```
[['Able'],['Baker'],['Charlie'],['Delta']]
```

The CSV recorder expects to write a row or a set of rows.  EACH ROW has to be a list (or tuple).  That's why I created it like I did.  By calling `writerows`, the outer list contains the set of rows to be written.  Each element of the outer list is a row.  I want each row to contain one item, so each is a one element list.

If I had created this:

```
['Able','Baker','Charlie','Delta']
```

then `writerows` would have treated each string as a sequence, resulting in a CSV file like this:

```
A,b,l,e
B,a,k,e,r
C,h,a,r,l,i,e
D,e,l,t,a
```

which is amusing but not very useful.  And I know that because I did it while I was creating your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So basically you're assigning the Key to names and then passing it to the CSV, writing by each row. I'm still wrapping my head around this way but I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import csv

with open('boy-names.txt', 'rt') as file, open('boy-names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Column1'])
    for boy_name in sorted(file.readlines()):
        boy_name = boy_name.rstrip('\n')
        print(boy_name)
        csv_writer.writerow([boy_name])
```

Comment: My logic was telling me to open both documents at the same time, but apparently decided not to. I like your approach and I appreciate the reply!